# Android Studio, way to sync code for Google Ads supported app and the "Pro" version?

Tags: android, android-studio

When developing an app, one with adverts and the other "pro" version which customers can buy is there any way for Android Studio to sync the pair as apart from the google ads added they are identical. Or do you have to manually fix a bug in one version then duplicate the fix in the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors): you can declare a number of flavors, each mapped to its own source set, which gets merged with the main source set when you build a specific application flavor. The official documentation linked above actually provides an example of "demo" and "full" product flavors, which seems to be similar to your use case.